# Problems with Couchbase lite on iOS with WKWebView in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to run app from this article https://blog.couchbase.com/data-synchronization-with-couchbase-in-ionic-2-hybrid-mobile-apps/ I don't have any problem on android , but when I try to run it on iOS, app can't get access to local database, get this error - http://lite.couchbase./nraboy     Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. If I downgrade WKWebView to  UIWebView, everything is works.

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic implementation leverages the Couchbase Lite REST API which only works w. UIWebView.

Including the response from the [Developer Forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/problems-with-couchbase-lite-on-ios-with-wkwebview/16511) for benefit of those not on that forum.

> The CBL REST API only works with UIWebView, not WKWebView. The HTTP
>   handlers are registered through an in-process mechanism
>   (NSURLProtocol), but WKWebView actually runs in a separate process for
>   security reasons.